# What permissions should I give these files?

Tags: linux, permissions, bash, file-permissions, user-permissions

I have some files that `nobody` needs read access to and `apache` needs read and write access to.

Should I do

```
chown nobody.apache file
chmod 460 file
```

or

```
chown apache.nobody file
chmod 640 file
```

or perhaps something else?

Comment: Be careful when giving access to `nobody`.  I assume you're doing that because a process is running as nobody, but that is a general-purpose restricted access user and you might be granting access to more than you think.  Take a look to see how many processes are running as `nobody` before using it for permissions.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the case. openvpn is running as `nobody` so somehow `nobody` needs read permission to the secret certificates. `nobody` needs read access to the secret `index.txt` file and `apache` needs both read and write to this file also.

Comment: No!  No, no, no, no!  **No!!**  You should drop privileges instead using the user and group configuration directives, and restrict the keys to whoever will be launching it (preferably root).  If you create such a travesty everyone who has a shell will also have access to your VPN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment about secret certificates, you should definitely create a separate user to run OpenVPN (one called "`openvpn`" might be a good choice). The `nobody` user is (like Kyle Smith said) used as a general-purpose restricted access user, and you might be unwittingly giving access to your OpenVPN certificates to, say, anonymous FTP users.

I'd be inclined to solve the `index.txt` problem by adding the `apache` user to the `openvpn` group and make the file group-readable.

So:

1. create an `openvpn` user
2. run OpenVPN as that user
3. `usermod --append --groups openvpn apache`
4. `chown openvpn:openvpn /path/to/certificates /path/to/index.txt`
5. `chmod 600 /path/to/certificates`
6. `chmod 640 /path/to/index.txt`

Comment: Does the 3. command make the openvpn user member of the apache group?

Comment: No, it makes the `apache` user a member of the `openvpn` group

Answer (score 2):

The first one does not make much sense, as usually the user should be the one with more rights, and the **user can still change the rights of its own files** (this is not what you want).

So, expecting `nobody` is the only user of the `nobody` group, you should go for your 2nd solution:

```
chown apache:nobody file
chmod 640 file
```